# iOS VoiceOver reading accessibilityIdentifier instead of accessibilityLabel

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, voiceover

VoiceOver should read the `accessibilityLabel` property of any accessibility element on the screen. I have a `UIImageView` called `mediaImageView`, the code below sets up accessibility on this view and is called in `awakeFromNib` in a `UITableViewCell` subclass.

Rather than reading `image`, VoiceOver reads `articleMediaCell_image` which is the `accessibilityIdentifier`. Can anyone explain why this this could be happening?

(testing on device with iOS 13.3, issue happens whether or not custom actions are set)

```
    mediaImageView.isAccessibilityElement = true
    mediaImageView.accessibilityIdentifier = "articleMediaCell_image"
    mediaImageView.accessibilityLabel = "image"

    mediaImageView.accessibilityCustomActions = [
        UIAccessibilityCustomAction(
            name: "expand to fullscreen",
            target: self,
            selector: #selector(imageTapped)
        )
    ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens due to the fact that you have set the trait (image) of the control type as the value for `accessibilityLabel` here:

```
mediaImageView.accessibilityLabel = "image"
/*
This won't work, because iOS already knows that this is an image from the element's traits.
Due to this, the redundant value is ignored and the voiceover falls back to reading the `accessibilityIdentifier`.
*/
```

Use any value - **"media"** for example - that is other than the trait of the object, because the voiceover will read the accessibility label value followed by the trait of the control type like so: **"Media Image"**.

```
mediaImageView.accessibilityLabel = "media" /* This will work */
```

---

Excerpt from `accessibilityLabel` **[Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615181-accessibilitylabel):**

> Note that the label never includes the control type (such as button)
> because the traits of the accessibility element contain that
> information.

Answer (score 4):

Set the `accessibilityTraits` of your `mediaImageView` to `UIAccessibilityTraits.button`.

`mediaImageView.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraits.button`